# Php Info shows Incorrect Default timezone as UTC

Tags: php, linux, datetime, ubuntu, joomla

I have a Joomla installation in EC2 Ubuntu instance.
Problem is even though I have Updated Olson DB via PECL and added extension = timazonedb.so and date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata in php.ini file found in php5/apache and php5/cli.

Updated TZdata and its set to Asia/Kolkata.

And restarted apache several times but I cannot get the Joomla to use Default Time as Asia/Kolkata, as Its Always UTC.

Command  php  -i | grep -i timezone 
SHOWS ::

```
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2015.5
Timezone Database => external
Default timezone => Asia/Kolkata
date.timezone => Asia/Kolkata => Asia/Kolkata
timezonedb
Alternative Timezone Database => enabled
Timezone Database Version => 2015.5
```

Whereas in Joomla > System Info > Php Info > Date
SHOWS:

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2015.5
Timezone Database   external
Default timezone UTC
```

I need This UTC to work as Asia/Kolkata..

Any solutions Please Share, thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look in Site -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Location Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two php.ini files and you need to change them both. One is for Apache and the other for cli.

They are usually stored in `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

I suspect that you have only changed one of them.